# How do I do an in-place FFT on a subset of array in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a 2D array.  I want to run an (inverse) in-place FFT on one column.  The following produces no change in the data:

`ifft!( buf_FFT[:,ind_page], 1 )`

The following works as expected:

`buf_FFT[:,ind_page] = ifft( buf_FFT[:,ind_page] )`

The answer might be obvious but I am new to Julia and could not find the answer in a search.  I am assuming the first version does not work because when I specify the subset of the array, Julia actually makes a copy.  That copy is operated on but is then discarded.  In the second version, the copy gets copied back into the original array.  Is this correct?  What is the correct way to access a subset of an array in-place?

Please help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As you have guessed, taking a slice of an array creates a copy. The in-place ifft! function operates on this copy, and therefore does not affect the original array. To operate on a slice in-place, you should explicitly create a *view*. There are many ways to create a view, as shown in the code below (on `v0.5`). Choose one that works in your context.

```
buf_FFT = rand(Complex{Float64}, 10,10)
#in-place FFT on the first column of the matrix
ifft!( view(buf_FFT, 1:size(buf_FFT, 1),1), 1 ) 
#alternately, to save some typing:
ifft!( view(buf_FFT, Colon(), 1), 1 )
#Or, even simpler, use the @view macro
ifft!(@view(buf_FFT[:,1]), 1)
```

Documentation:

- http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/arrays/#Base.view
- http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/devdocs/subarrays/

Edit: added @view macro thanks to Simon's comment below.

Comment: You can also use the `@view` macro: `ifft!(@view(buf_FFT[:,1]), 1)`